# Lotus Notes: @Min from a list

Tags: list, lotus-notes, min

I have 5 numeric fields: `n1` , ... , `n5`.

Also, there is another numeric field called `min`. This field have the following formula:

`@Min(@Trim(n1):@Trim(n2):@Trim(n3):@Trim(n4):@Trim(n5))` but i get the message:

```
....@Function: Text expected
```

I appreciate your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `@Trim` to eliminate empty values this way:

```
@Min(@ToNumber(@Trim(@Text(n1) : @Text(n2) : @Text(n3) : @Text(n4) : @Text(n5))))
```

If all n1 ... n5 are empty then result will be 0.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Now I get : ... @Function: Number expected. Hmm